# SQL: How to subtract two SUM() functions results from two different queries

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have this [structure of the DB][image: 1]

and I have to make a sumatory of the whole items bought, minus every item bought of people who didn't buy an specific category of food 'PANADERIA'.

The thing is that I know how to get both sumatories, but I don't find the way to subtract them.

With that sentence, I'm getting the sumatory of every item bought:

```
SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
FROM CLIENTE CL
JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
```

And with that I'm getting the sumatory of the rest which CATEGORIA is not 'PANADERIA':

```
SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
FROM CLIENTE CL
JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
JOIN PRODUCTO PR ON PR.IDP = CO.IDP
JOIN CATEGORIA CA ON CA.IDC = PR.IDC
WHERE CA.CATEGORIA = 'PANADERIA'
```

The results are (58 - 5) in this case, right now, but I'd like to calculate it automatically

Comment: can you pls tag database ?

Answer (score 0):

If both of your queries already give you the result you want, just wrap them into another `SELECT`.

Give this one a try:

```
SELECT (
    (
        SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
        FROM CLIENTE CL
        JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
    )
    -
    (
        SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
        FROM CLIENTE CL
        JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
        JOIN PRODUCTO PR ON PR.IDP = CO.IDP
        JOIN CATEGORIA CA ON CA.IDC = PR.IDC
        WHERE CA.CATEGORIA = 'PANADERIA'
    )

)
```

Comment: It says that I actually need to use the keyword FROM.

So I placed it and also a random table and then I got 5 rows, then added distinct to the begin of the sentence after the SELECT and it works. Now I'm getting only one row with the number 53.

Comment: You didn't post the RDBMS, some of them don't need a `FROM`. MySQL: `SELECT 
(
 (SELECT (5*2) AS 'A' )
 -
 (SELECT (2+3) AS 'A')
)`   works just fine. But yes, your workaround might help out here.

Comment: I'm sorry man, It's my first time that I come to stackoverflow to ask for some help. Anyways thank you so much.

Comment: No problem... glad I helped you on the right track.

Comment: `FROM dual` for Oracle. Which is exactly why you should tag your DB to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify this code as follow:

```
    SELECT (
(
    SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
    FROM CLIENTE CL
    JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
)
-
(
    SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
    FROM CLIENTE CL
    JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
    JOIN PRODUCTO PR ON PR.IDP = CO.IDP
    JOIN CATEGORIA CA ON CA.IDC = PR.IDC
    WHERE CA.CATEGORIA = 'PANADERIA'
)

    ) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you just want `CA.CATEGORIA != 'PANADERIA'`

```
SELECT SUM(CO.CANTIDAD) 
FROM CLIENTE CL
JOIN COMPRA CO ON CO.DNI = CL.DNI
JOIN PRODUCTO PR ON PR.IDP = CO.IDP
JOIN CATEGORIA CA ON CA.IDC = PR.IDC
WHERE CA.CATEGORIA != 'PANADERIA'
```